# Vim wont split open a directory from python, but it works interactively

Tags: linux, vim, python

I'm having an issue that is confusing me. I can split-open a directory just fine using normal vim syntax, but when I use the python bindings something goes wrong. The problem only exists with directories. Files work just fine.

Here are some MWEs:

If I execute the command

`:split /home`

**It works** A new split panel is open, and I see the contents of my hope directory.

---

If I run a function that contains the lines

```
func! MySplit() 
:split /home
endfu
```

and I run `:call MySplit`, **It works** as expected.

---

However, If I define the funciton

```
func! MySplitPy() 
python3 << EOF
import vim
vim.command(':split /home')
EOF
endfu
```

and call :call MySplitPy`, then **it fails**, the screen blinks and nothing happens

---

If I add a print to this

```
func! MySplitPy() 
python3 << EOF
import vim
vim.command(':split /home')
print('foo')
EOF
endfu
```

**it fails**, but the following output prints to the screen:

```
"/home" is a directory
foo
```

---

Its weird that it is complaining about a directory, so I checked it is ok if I specify a file instead:

```
func! MySplitPy() 
python3 << EOF
import vim
vim.command(':split /home/joncrall/.bashrc')
EOF
endfu
```

**it works**.

---

My question is: Why does `vim.command(':split {}'.format(path))` work when `path` is a file, but not when it is a directory?

EDIT: vim info

---

```
(venv3) joncrall@calculex:~/code/VIAME/build/build/src/kwiver-build$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 24 2016 16:44:48)
Included patches: 1-1689
Extra patches: 8.0.0056
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Huge version with GTK2-GNOME GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     +tcl
+browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     +terminfo
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +termresponse
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +textobjects
+channel         +gettext         -mzscheme        +timers
+cindent         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
+clientserver    +iconv           +packages        +toolbar
+clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +job             +perl            +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3         +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con_gui  +lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           +xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     +xsmp_interact
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      +startuptime     +xterm_clipboard
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_save
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    +xpm
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -D_REENTRANT -DORBIT2=1 -pthread -I/usr/include/libgnomeui-2.0 -I/usr/include/gnome-keyring-1 -I/usr/include/libbonoboui-2.0 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/libgnome-2.0 -I/usr/include/libbonobo-2.0 -I/usr/include/bonobo-activation-2.0 -I/usr/include/orbit-2.0 -I/usr/include/libgnomecanvas-2.0 -I/usr/include/gail-1.0 -I/usr/include/libart-2.0 -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/gnome-vfs-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-vfs-2.0/include -I/usr/include/gconf/2 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -Wdate-time  -g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-E  -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype  -lgnomeui-2 -lSM -lICE -lbonoboui-2 -lgnome-2 -lpopt -lbonobo-2 -lbonobo-activation -lORBit-2 -lgnomecanvas-2 -lart_lgpl_2 -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgnomevfs-2 -lgconf-2 -lgthread-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl  -L/usr/lib -llua5.2 -Wl,-E  -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22/CORE -lperl -ldl -lm -lpthread -lcrypt  -L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.5m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ltcl8.6 -ldl -lz -lpthread -lieee -lm -lruby-2.3 -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm
```

I have the following plugins:

```
(venv3) joncrall@calculex:~/.vim/bundle$ ls ~/.vim/bundle/
AnsiEsc.vim  LaTeX-Box      supertab   taglist.vim  vim-autopep8          vim-powerline    vim-startify
badwolf      nerdcommenter  syntastic  ultisnips    vim-colors-solarized  vim-searchindex  vim-virtualenv
jedi-vim     nerdtree       tagbar     unicode.vim  vim-markdown          vim-snippets
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with Vim 8.0.987 and Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04. Your `MySplitPy()` function works as expected. What are your versions / environment?

Comment: The `:split` with a directory triggers the _netrw_ plugin via `:autocmd`s. It shouldn't matter that the call is from Python, though.

Comment: That's very weird that you can reproduce. I have almost the same versions. I ended up hacking around this by changing command to use `':Hexplore {fpath}'.format(fpath=fpath)` fpath is a directory. However, it uses the netrw view and not the the NERDTree view like I wish it would. :(

Comment: Oh, you should have mentioned that you're using NERDTree! I still cannot reproduce, though. The NERDTree view still opens just fine. You could try disabling all other plugins and your .vimrc configuration temporarily.